# iOS How to form sqlite like statement?

Tags: ios, sqlite

Code:

```
@try {
        if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char * sql="Select Id, Name,Designation, Skill, Credits, Selected from candidate_info where Designation like '%%%@%%'";

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [searchWord UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) ==SQLITE_ROW)
                {


                }
            }
            else
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error in candidateinfo. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
    }@catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception is %@, %@", [e name], [e reason]);
    }@finally {
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
```

I try to fetch data from sqlite based on search keyword.I tried with like statement.The query is not executing and is goes out of while loop.what is wrong with my code.thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure query you are making, returns data by using any sqlmanager ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your Query using `NSString` :

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select Id, Name,Designation, Skill, Credits, Selected from candidate_info where Designation like '%@'", searchWord] ;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{

}
```

Problem is that you are using 'sqlite3_bind_text' in wrong way.
Your query must be :

```
const char * sql="Select Id, Name,Designation, Skill, Credits, Selected from candidate_info where Designation like '%%?%%'";
```

You are missing '?'

Comment: Print you query, copy it, and fire it in your sqlite using any SQLManager..!! I am pretty sure, its not returning any data.

Comment: Select Id, Name,Designation, Skill, Credits, Selected from candidate_info where Designation like '%%s%%'. this is what tested in sqlite manager.it is returning data

Comment: Try passing any hardcoded query, and check whether it works or not. If it works, then nothing is wrong with query making and execution, then start checking rest of the things like database path etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question

```
 NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select Id, Name,Designation, Skill, Credits, Selected from candidate_info where Designation LIKE '%%%@%%'", searchWord];
 const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
```